# PHP find bubble in array range of numbers

Tags: php, arrays

Sample Array

```
$array = [

    61029,
    64698,
    67355,
    70000, // has bubble
    43651,
    48346,
    52029,  // has bubble 
    48029,
    48698,
    49355,
    50000,

    ];
```

How to identify the arrays are Ascending order and Descending order and it has a bubble also

Comment: Need more description? what is `bubble` here?

Comment: A bubble means top up

e.g. One guy took a loan of 50000, after four months of he got offer to top up loan

Comment: `max()` function?

Comment: the max() method is fine, I need to find out which array value has a bubble, I need to remove values after the bubble, Bubble can me multiple times

Comment: `array_search` or `array_keys` will give you keys of founded value.

Comment: the array_search method we need to provide the value to find, we can't predict the value in the dynamic array

Comment: What is the expected result and why ?

Comment: Please update your question with (1)What is your expected result? (2) What is bubble?

Comment: I _guess_ by “bubble” you mean the last value in sequence that presents an increase over the previous value …? Well then all you had to do is compare the current value to the previous one, in a loop, no?

Comment: I need to eliminate  the array values above bubbles, Means when a bubble is there, ignore above array values, calc only below values

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by or how you define “bubble.” No one here so far seems to have a clear idea of what you mean by that.

Comment: Do you mean crest?

Comment: 61029,
64698,
67355,
70000, // has bubble
43651,
48346,
52029,  // has bubble 
48029,
48698,
49355,  
50000

These numbers are in e.g. bank statements,


Month2 = 48698,
Month1 =49355,
Month0 =50000

Month0 - Month1 = 645 is principal amount

If suddenly he has an extra amount in the middle of the month if do math while in the bubble we will get a negative value, is there any way to find out arrays has mixed values and split the values by Ascending or descending order

Answer (score 1):

(The below are my assumptions, please let me know if I am right/wrong.)

Bubble context: Lender takes out a loan. Lender pays back loan. Halfway thru paying back, takes up another loan.

Bubble technical: Array contains balances in descending order. If the value increases (compared to the last), it's deemed a bubble.

Here's how you identify a bubble in an array:

```
<?php

/**
 * An array in DESCENDING order (OP)
 */
$array = [
    61029,
    64698,
    67355,
    70000, // has bubble
    43651,
    48346,
    52029,  // has bubble 
    48029,
    48698,
    49355,
    50000,
];

/**
 * An array in ASCENDING order
 */
$asc_array = [
    10,
    20,
    30,
    40,
    50,
    45, //Has bubble
    55
];

/**
 * Given an array, identify a "bubble",
 * aka. an increasing value in an otherwise decreasing value array.
 * Returns the $key where the bubble resides.
 */ 
function identifyBubble($array){
    foreach($array as $id => $item){
        if(!$id){
            continue;
        }
        if(!$array[$id+1]){
            continue;
        }
        if(($array[$id-1] < $array[$id]) && ($array[$id] > $array[$id+1])){
            return $id;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * If an array is in ASCENDING order, switch it around,
 * otherwise return the array as is.
 */
function makeArrayDescending($array){
    if(reset($array) < end($array)){
        return array_values(array_reverse($array));
    }
    return $array;
}

var_dump(identifyBubble($array));

var_dump(makeArrayDescending($asc_array));

var_dump(identifyBubble(makeArrayDescending($asc_array)));
```

**Output**

```
int(3)
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(55)
  [1]=>
  int(45)
  [2]=>
  int(50)
  [3]=>
  int(40)
  [4]=>
  int(30)
  [5]=>
  int(20)
  [6]=>
  int(10)
}
int(2)
```

**Caveats**

This will only work on associated arrays (arrays with number indexes that are in order). This will only work on one-dimensional arrays.

https://3v4l.org/9UNY6

Comment: Keep in mind this will only work on indexed arrays, on associative arrays it will fail

Comment: @Andreas, you're absolutely right. I will add that as a caveat.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array and see if the value is less than the previous value.
If it is then the previous value was a bubble.

```
$prev = 0;
foreach($array as $a){
    if($a>$prev){
        $prev = $a;
    }else{
        $result[] = $prev;
        $prev = $a;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
//70000, 52029
```

https://3v4l.org/8qWMI